# plot_geo auto zoom to contain data

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to default an image view to contain all of the requisite data, but the use of `geo=list(lonaxis=list(range=...))` (etc) does not seem to work well.

Sample data:

```r
simpleouter <- structure(list(lon = c(-81.0734678057973, -81.0734601579696, -81.0734484550107, -81.073432854577, -81.0733975145945, -81.0733485079183, -81.0732831359724, -81.0731812806164, -81.0730524130359, -81.0728906244642, -81.0727090833668, -81.0725019262647, -81.0723014647303, -81.0720967621774, -81.0719082785736, -81.0717436469846, -81.071614504076, -81.0715213695205, -81.0714600006159, -81.0714323729392, -81.071425721998, -81.071427563867, -81.0714322028664, -81.0714380750906, -81.0714464199606, -81.0714530639244,  -81.0714640404429, -81.0714800641876, -81.0715059212406, -81.0715433428489, -81.071599319322, -81.071677889326, -81.0717877232053, -81.0719321530166, -81.0720988405724, -81.0723014516816, -81.0725095759708, -81.0727193041855, -81.0729367591727, -81.0731089339929, -81.0732592271676, -81.0733793035935, -81.0734562958247, -81.0735019858925, -81.073510465099, -81.0735055240372, -81.0734963728656, -81.0734851511663, -81.0734762589249, -81.0734678057973), lat = c(36.1425767539004, 36.1424138565364, 36.1422518558661,  36.1420945996656, 36.1419238576038, 36.1417608334235, 36.1415958346638, 36.1414488456951, 36.1413325492495, 36.1412337378155, 36.1411770225236, 36.1411501121235, 36.1411551029806, 36.1411947363256, 36.1412567633342, 36.1413516010283, 36.1414689258078, 36.1416090539297, 36.1417671808467, 36.1419313886788, 36.1420963442737, 36.1422599667132, 36.1424210284474, 36.1425815651978, 36.1427416685307, 36.1429020900657, 36.143064189833, 36.1432273939696, 36.1433906279054, 36.1435537242213, 36.143711749163,  36.1438644855146, 36.1440017047475, 36.1441191188712, 36.1442041432813, 36.1442601787495, 36.1442796271737, 36.1442597621632, 36.144200682876, 36.1441142527926, 36.1439965570493, 36.1438585184451, 36.1437153222574, 36.1435554462018, 36.1433899286698, 36.1432220633474, 36.1430531756022, 36.142893872586, 36.1427344295017, 36.1425767539004)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

A simple plot is

```r
library(plotly)

plot_geo(simpleouter, x = ~lon, y = ~lat) %>%
  add_paths() %>%
  plotly::layout(geo = list(
    fitbounds = "locations"
  ))
```

[image: plotly, not zoomed in]

Note how the top/bottom of the display are cropped. The ideal view is something like this:

[image: plotly, properly zoomed around the existing data]

When I try to constrain the view, I thought the best way is with `geo=list(lonaxis=list(range = ...), lataxis=list(range = ...))`, but when I define that based on the range of each axis, the display is overly-constrained.

```r
lims <- lapply(simpleouter[,c("lon", "lat")], range)
lims
# $lon
# [1] -81.07351 -81.07143
# $lat
# [1] 36.14115 36.14428

plot_geo(simpleouter, x = ~lon, y = ~lat) %>%
  add_paths() %>%
  plotly::layout(geo = list(
    fitbounds = "locations"
   ,lonaxis = list(range=lims$lon), lataxis = list(range=lims$lat)
  ))
```

[image: plotly, x-axis is too tight]

This is not what I want because (1) the x-axis is not as wide as the intended data, and I do not want the bounding box to change from the initial view far above.

The real data varies (per plot) in the location (lon/lat), the size (1/2 mile to 2+ miles often), and the aspect ratio (some oblong, some more square-like), so I cannot hard-code the actual zoom or the lon/lat limits. I'm looking for a plotly-native (not `ggplotly(..)`) way to intuitively set the initial zoom/bounds (and not restrict follow-on user zooming). Additionally, there will eventually be upwards of 1000s of points added, so `leaflet` and similar will likely have plotting performance issues.

Comment: while toying around with the example provided, I found that reversing the `lims$lon` and `lims$lat` (using `rev()`) in your axis calls displays the trace quite nicely. Do you know why this is? It could just be a coincidence, or maybe I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: Forgot to include that I removed the `fitbounds` argument entirely, although that only mildly changes the output.

Comment: That's very interesting, @542goweast! It doesn't perfectly resolve it (the bounding box itself is still over-constrained), but that does certainly make it less of an eye-sore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Geo maps I was unable to obtain the requested result. However using Mapbox maps it seems possible to manually set the zoom level (see [reference](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/)). Now I also think it is possible to link the zoom level to the bounding box of your paths but it looks a bit complex (see [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/scattermapbox-setting-visible-range/6140)).

In alternative you can preset a zoom level that works for most of your data (it should be feasible within the range you talk about (1/2 - 2miles).

Another possibility is to change approach using `leaflet` or `mapview`.

## CODE

In mapbox you need to specify an underlying base map or a white background (see [reference2](https://plotly.com/r/mapbox-layers/))

```
fig <- plot_ly(simpleouter, lon = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
  
  type = 'scattermapbox', mode = 'lines', size = I(10)) 


fig <- fig %>%
  
  layout(
    
    mapbox = list(
      
      style = "open-street-map", # use "white-bg" for white background
      
      center = list(lon = mean(simpleouter$lon), lat = mean(simpleouter$lat) ),

      zoom = 15),
       
    showlegend = FALSE)
```

## RESULT:

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks! For context, leaflet is too slow with the number of points we'll be throwing at it, so we're unlikely to go in that direction unless that is resolved. I appreciate the note about `"white-bg"` and such. My point about 0.5 to 2 miles, though, is that I want it to default to putting the object in full zoom on the screen, not to set a zoom that will encompass all objects between 1/2 and 2 miles across. It works for some objects (seemingly for those that are _wider_ than tall), so I'm trying to resolve why it cannot fit the provided data.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, but have you seen https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl?